# Why does ctrl+pageDown not work when assigned to Window.nextDocumentWindow?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to reassign the keyboard shortcut for moving between editor tabs in Visual Studio.

When I assign ctrl+pageDown to  Window.nextDocumentWindow it does not work. I can successfully assign other key combinations to this same command and it work. But ctrl+pageDown does not.

Comment: Works on my machine.  There's always a risk that another process is stealing keystrokes.  Try finding it by using Task Manager to kill running processes one by one.  First check that the existing binding (Edit.ViewBottom) is broken as well.

Comment: It is not something eating the keystroke. It just keeps executing the original command instead of the remapped one.

Comment: I routinely forget to click the Assign button after setting up the key binding.